# Laravel 5 - where to place uploaded image handler logic?

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-5, code-organization

In my project there will be several places where I need to use uploading image form.

On server side I use L5 and I want to make uploaded image handler with:

- check image type
- check image size
- moving uploaded image to uploads folder
- throw exceptions in case of any errors.

I'd like to to make it in Laravel-way :) Where is right place to put that logic, so I can reuse it in several places?

Comment: This sounds like a great job for a Command Bus - http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/bus

Comment: @TheShiftExchange thanks, I'm reading this manual now.

Comment: Command Bus sounds OK but it should not contain the actual image manipulation logic. What you need is a simple library. So create a directory in the App dir (you'll organize there all your non-controller, non-model logic) and create your class inside. Namsespace it correctly and just use it all over your application or if you want you can use it inside the command.

Answer (score 0):

An image upload function is often one of the first things I'll do in a Laravel app.  I will normally create a Helper folder in the App directory and in there create an Upload class which I'll call for any uploads. The method saved my butt when I went from  Forge hosted environment to Heroku and learned that uploads won't persist on the server and had to insert an S3 upload method. Took me about 20 minutes to get S3 running and it worked everywhere I had uploads in the app.